VS NuGet Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1 How extract delegates
The context is Google API (Admin SDK API).
My question is: Using nuget package Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1 is possible to extract a list of delegates for single user?
I tryed this code, but service.Users.Delegates.List(userEmail) don't exist...help me please!
Thank's in advance for every suggestion :)
[..]
var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    ApplicationName = "Application name",
    HttpClientInitializer = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonKeyFilePath)
        .CreateScoped(DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly)
        .CreateWithUser(userEmail)
});

var request = service.Users.Delegates.List(userEmail);
var response = await request.ExecuteAsync();
[..]


Rather than focusing on the .NET SDK, can you identify which REST call you're looking for? See https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest - once you've worked that part out, expressing it in .NET should be easy.

Thanks to @JonSkeet but Delegates is not among the available methods :( Hope someone has an alternative to suggest ;)

Using the suggestion of @JonSkeet(explore REST approach) I solved my problem :)
[..]
string apiEndpoint = $"https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/settings/delegates";
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiEndpoint);
var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
[..]

Well now that you've identified the API you actually want to use, you can just use Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 instead, I suspect. (With service.Users.Settings.Delegates at a guess.)
